# Unable to fetch ENV values from docker to Angular application

Tags: angular, docker

I am not able to fetch the `ENV` values which are passed with docker run command to `environment.ts` file of my angular application. I am explaining the docker file below.

**Dockerfile**

```
         FROM node:12-alpine as angular-build
            #FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
            
            RUN echo "NODE Version:" && node --version
            RUN echo "NPM Version:" && npm --version
            
            COPY ./app /app
            
            WORKDIR /app/mean-stack/angular-js
            RUN npm install
            #COPY . /app/mean-stack/angular-js
            RUN npm run build --prod
            
       
        COPY install-nginx-alpine.sh /
    
    RUN sh /install-nginx-alpine.sh
    
    EXPOSE 90
    
    # # Expose 443, in case of LTS / HTTPS
    EXPOSE 443
 ENV STATIC_URL /site
# Absolute path in where the static files wil be
ENV STATIC_PATH /app/static/angular

# If STATIC_INDEX is 1, serve / with /static/index.html directly (or the static URL configured)
# ENV STATIC_INDEX 1
ENV STATIC_INDEX 0

# Add demo app
COPY ./app /app


WORKDIR /app/mean-stack/node-js
RUN echo "$WORKDIR"
RUN pwd
RUN ls -lt
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8081


# Angular resources
#WORKDIR /app/mean-stack/angular-js
#RUN npm install
#COPY . /app/mean-stack/angular-js
#RUN npm run build --prod

RUN mkdir /app/static/angular
COPY --from=angular-build /app/mean-stack/angular-js/dist/ubot /app/static/angular

# When the container starts, replace the env.js with values from environment variables
CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /app/static/angular/assets/env.template.js > /app/static/angular/assets/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

I am using the below `docker run` command to run my application.

```
docker run -d -it -p 8999:90 -p 1901:8081 --env NODE_PORT=1901 --name test-container-ubot  ubot-container:latest
```

Here `8999` hosting port of angular and `90` is the container port. similarly `1901` is the hosting port for some other application which is present inside same `Dockerfile`(`I have not mentioned my total` Dockerfile`code only given the`angular `part.`)

Here My need is to fetch the `NODE_PORT=1901` to angular `environment.ts` file. I am explaining my angular code below.

**assets/env.js**

```
(function(window) {
    window["env"] = window["env"] || {};

    // Environment variables
    window["env"]["nodePort"] = 1900;
    console.log('env port', window["env"]["nodePort"]);
})(this);
```

**assets/env.template.js**

```
(function(window) {
    window.env = window.env || {};
    console.log('template', "${NODE_PORT}");
    // Environment variables
    window["env"]["nodePort"] = "${NODE_PORT}";
})(this);
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Unified Test Automation</title>
  <base href="/site/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="assets/env.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/cisco_logo.png">
</head>
<body class="cui" style="overflow:auto">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**environment.ts:**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  nodeJsBaseUrl: `http://${window.location.hostname}`,
  hostingNodeJsContainerPort: window["env"]["nodePort"] || 1900
};
```

Here idea is when docker will run the `env.js` values will replaced with environment variable from docker command line. so accordingly  `window["env"]["nodePort"] = 1900` should be  `window["env"]["nodePort"] = 1901` but in my case the env values from docker is not replacing the original value. I need to pass some environment variable from docker command and set inside angular `environment.ts` file. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: what about running `sed` and replace ${NODE_PORT} with the value from the environment?

Comment: @Mogi: I did not get you. Can you please post your answer in details.

Comment: `RUN "sed 's/${NODE_PORT}/1901/' assets/env.template.js"` in dockerfile

Comment: @Mogi: this `1901` can not be static value. always the port no may change while running container.

Comment: So you can use `ARG` in the dockerfile: `ARG nodeport` and then `RUN "sed 's/${NODE_PORT}/$nodeport/' assets/env.template.js"` and when you build the image use `docker build --build-arg nodeport=1901 .`. If it solves your problem I would happily post it as an answer

Comment: by the way another solution is to keep the use of environment variables, and start the container using env argument if you run it with `docker` or within the yml file if you run it using `docker-compose`

Comment: @Mogi: Ok I will try than but my docker buils command is `docker build -t ubot-container .` so as per you how it will be.

Comment: @Mogi: But how it will replace with `env.js` file in angular because that file has included into `index.html`. Ultimately my aim is to fetch this value in angular environment file.

Comment: @Mogi: I did as per you but its throwing `/bin/sh: sed 's//1905/' /app/static/angular/assets/env.template.js: not found` error.

Comment: if you want to use the sed solution you need to run `docker build -t ubot-container . --build-arg nodeport=1901`, if you want to use the environment solution (which is better in my opinion) build the image as you did before with environment variables and then when you run the docker add the env variable